# how can I get information in rich:pickList?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I created my rich:pickList by follow an example from richfaces 
http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=pickList&skin=blueSky

My problem is that no information display in Selected list. So how can I get it ?

```
My Edit.xhtml file:
<rich:pickList value="#{controller.selectedStudent}" var="f" sourceCaption="Available" targetCaption="Selected" listWidth="195px" listHeight="100px" orderable="true">
    <f:selectItems value="#{controller.studentList}" var="test" itemValue="#{test}" itemLabel="#{test.name}" />
</rich:pickList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an error from richfaces picklist because the selected items (Right) must be the same object as pick list in the Left

1. Create 2 lists: Left pick list and Right selected list.
2. find element in Left pick list and put it into Right selected list.

Comment: It is not the most intuitive implementation but it makes sense to assume that the selected items are a subset of the available items, perhaps the component is a bit too smart in that case and violates the principle of least surprise.